# How to get the string value of a UItextView?

Tags: iphone, text

I have a UITextView and a NString;

I made this:

```
myS = [myInfoTextView text];
```

but i get this in the console and not the string which is in the uitextview

```
 (
    "<UIToolbarTextButton: 0x4d200c0; frame = (6 0; 112 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4da5540>>",
    "<UIToolbarTextButton: 0x4da5bb0; frame = (128 0; 106 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4d9e640>>"
)
```

PS: I'm using the iphone sdk 4.2.

Comment: That's strange... it should give you an `NSString`. Are you logging the correct object?

Comment: NSLog(@"1: %@", frontCardText);

Comment: Can u post your original code?

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 frontCardText = [myInfoTextView text];
 backCardText = [myInfoTextView text];
 
}

Comment: in the interface builder my textview has this text: "infos..."

Comment: but if i do this: NSLog(@"TEXT: %@",[myInfoTextView text]);
it's all fine

Comment: i solved it it was released...i just made a property and it works now but thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the above code, try this

```
NSString *textValue = [NString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTextView.text];
NSLog(@"%@", textValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the specification of the ToolBar Button.You are not getting the value of Text view in string and moreover you are not priting it with NSLog.You get the text in the console by printing it with NSLog.
Do it the way as Snehal is saying.

```
NSString *textValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTextView.text];
NSLog(@"Text Value is %@", textValue);
```

Hope you will get to the desired output.

Comment: Please note the typo should be NSString, not NString, right?