# TextKit and VoiceOver

Tags: ios, voiceover, textkit, uiaccessibility

I've been following the iOS7 Day-by-Day multi-page TextKit tutorial, and ran into an issue with accessibility. The code for the tutorial is here: [iOS7 Day-by-Day](https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day/blob/master/21-multi-column-textkit/21-multi-column-textkit.md)

The problem is that each of the text views (one per column, two per "page") seems to contain the entire string, and with VoiceOver enabled, every time a column gets the focus, the text is read from the very beginning of the string to the very end, instead of reading the text that is actually visible in a column.

The textviews/columns are created using the new iOS7 method

`UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame
                                           textContainer:textContainer];`

How can I get VoiceOver to read only the visible text in each column?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to determine what text is visible and then pass that to VoiceOver.

To do that, you can use the [two possible methods found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067803/ios-how-to-find-what-is-the-visible-range-of-text-in-uitextview) and with the range of the visible text, [you can then create a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565301/how-to-get-the-string-value-of-a-uitextview) via something like:

```
NSString *textToPassToVoiceOver = [[textView.text] rangeOfSubstring:visibleTextRange];
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Kinda. Isn't it a little weird to have to calculate the visible range of text again after just doing the calculation of how to fit it into columns and text containers? Also, how do I pass the substring to VoiceOver? Does that mean that I have to set the accessibility.label for each textview manually? This all feels like a workaround. Why isn't the textviews text property simply set to the text container it represents?